# A document that opens in a few hours on a web page

Tags: html, web

I want to open a file on a web page that will be available in a few hours. How can this be done?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you provide more details? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.